# why does http post request gives me high memory usage in go?

Tags: go

I have a `go` application running inside K8S container. It works as a rest api and receive request and write them request to Elasticsearch.

The code I have is:

```golang
var r = gin.Default()
r.POST("/logs", func(c *gin.Context) {
        fmt.Println("receive log event")
        PrintMemUsage()
        jsonData, err := ioutil.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)
        d := strings.NewReader(jsonData)
        http.Post(fmt.Sprintf("%s/_bulk", getEsHost()), "application/json", d)
        ...
    })
}
```

In above code, it listens on path `/logs` and call `http` to save the data in Elasticsearch. When I use below function to print the memory usage, I can see the `Alloc` keeps increasing until run out of memory. The memory usage is consistently on 1 to 3MB if I remove the `http.Post` call. What could be the reason causing memory usage keep increasing?

```golang
func bToMb(b uint64) uint64 {
    return b / 1024 / 1024
}
func PrintMemUsage() {
    var m runtime.MemStats
    runtime.ReadMemStats(&m)
    // For info on each, see: https://golang.org/pkg/runtime/#MemStats
    fmt.Printf("Alloc = %v MiB", bToMb(m.Alloc))
    fmt.Printf("\tTotalAlloc = %v MiB", bToMb(m.TotalAlloc))
    fmt.Printf("\tSys = %v MiB", bToMb(m.Sys))
    fmt.Printf("\tNumGC = %v\n", m.NumGC)
}
```

Comment: `jsonData, err := ioutil.ReadAll(c.Request.Body)` this function reads the entire request body into memory,also can you try closing the `request.Body` with `defer c.Request.Body.Close()`

Comment: @ShubhamDixit, request body is automatically closed. Handler doesnt need to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [http docs](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#pkg-overview) mention a few times that:

> The client must close the response body when finished with it:

Here is the example from the docs:

```golang
resp, err := http.Get("http://example.com/")
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
defer resp.Body.Close()
body, err := io.ReadAll(resp.Body)
// ...
```

If you don't do that, you have a leak, as the body will stay in memory forever.